# Can't figure out how to set Attribute Value (Java DOM Parser)

Tags: java, xml

I've just started using Java this year in grade 12(final year of high school). And I need a "Data storage" for a game I am working on. I just want to create user saves and such.

I am attempting to make a "Skip" button(JButton) that *skips a day* in the game. I can get the values I need from the XML file(after a few days of struggling to figure it out), I just cannot set the value of my .

I have tried a few varieties of my same idea. I would get it in the same why I am already. Then stored the value in an int like *int example = Integer.parseInt(Node.getAttribute("Days"));* and increased the int by then then converting it back to a String using *Node.setAttribute("Days").setNodeValue(Integer.toString(example));* But I don't understand XML and Java to think of another solution

XmlController:

```
public Document getDoc() {
        //IMPORT FILE
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = dBuilder.parse(XMLReader.class.getResourceAsStream("/FreeplayData.xml"));
            doc.normalize();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //IMPORT FILE
        return(doc);
    }

//getPlayerDays
    public int getPlayerDays() {
        int d = 0;

        //IMPORT FILE
        Document doc = getDoc();
        //IMPORT FILE

        //TO-DO: Update Days counter
        Node mainClass = doc.getDocumentElement(); //Class
        NodeList mcList = mainClass.getChildNodes(); //Class List
        for (int i = 0; i < mcList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node cNode = mcList.item(i); //Player
            if (cNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) { //If currentNode is an element Node
                Element cElement = (Element)cNode; //Player
                String days = cElement.getAttribute("Days");
                d = Integer.parseInt(days);
            }
        }
        return(d);
    }

    public void setPlayerDays() {
        //IMPORT FILE
        Document doc = getDoc();
        //IMPORT FILE

        Node mainNode = doc.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList mainNodeList = mainNode.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < mainNodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node cNode = mainNodeList.item(i);
            if (cNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                NamedNodeMap cNodeAttributes = cNode.getAttributes();
                Node cNodeDays = cNodeAttributes.getNamedItem("Days");
                int value = Integer.parseInt(cNodeDays.getNodeValue());
                System.out.println(value); //Testing
                value = value + 1;
                cNodeDays.setNodeValue(Integer.toString(value));
                System.out.println(value); //Testing
            }
        }
    }
```

MainClass that calls XmlController:

```
//actionListners
        skipButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                Refresh();
            }
        });
    }

    public void Refresh() {
        daysLabel.setText("DAYS: " + XC.getPlayerDays());
        XC.setPlayerDays(); //XC is my XmlController Class
    }
```

XML: (I used Eclipse XML GUI to create the XML document pardon any Syntax errors :(  )

```
<?=? xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
<Class>
  <Player Name="Andrew" Rank="Newbie" ID="1" Days="0">
  </Player>
</Class>
```

When I press the skip button it keeps giving me 0, instead of increasing by 1 every time like I'd like

Comment: Bump ~ Anyone have any suggestions. Trying my best and I might just try use FileOutputStream/FileInputStream but I am worried with the amount of variables/objects I want to save that I will lose track...

Comment: Looks like you get the document, increment the value but then dont save it back. I assume you want to save the document after each click? Also you could just read the document once instead of every time. Aka make a property Document and make `getDoc()` return that document

Comment: I somewhat understand what you were saying. I AM changing it but not saving it? But I don't totally understand the read once part. I thought that is what I do in the `getDoc()` method, sorry I am brand new to XML and don't quiet under stand readers/writes(If that's what you call them???parser???)...

Comment: When you read the document it parses the file into memory. You then access the objects like your doing but modifying those objects dont have any affect on the file which they were parsed from. To persist your changes you will need to write the Document you modified back to the file

Comment: So creating a method to write the file with the new changes, then reread the new save of the file before attempting to display the JLabel with the counter should fix my problem? Also I was away all weekend, sorry for the late reply.